# my app getting rejected for Violation of section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement

Tags: android, youtube-api, admob, android-youtube-api

I am trying to add any kind of monetizing to my app, but when I add an admob banner or interstitial and submit the update, it gets rejected.

The application only views a Youtube player and loads playlist from my You tube account so it gets all data from youtube api.

I've tried to add an activity and put the ads in it and show it on app exit, but also got rejected.

My question is how to monetize the application without getting rejected.

Here is the rejection notification message.

This is a notification that your application submission, Muslim Kids Tube, for package ID kidstibe.ahmed.myapplication, has been rejected. If this submission was an update to an existing app, the version published prior to this update is still available on Google Play.

Please address the issue described below, then submit an update with your changes.

REASON FOR REJECTION:Violation of section 4.4 of the Developer Distribution Agreement.

After a regular review, we have determined that your app downloads, monetizes, or otherwise accesses YouTube videos in violation of the YouTube Terms of Service or YouTube API Terms of Service. Accessing content, a product, or service in an unauthorized manner is a violation of the Developer Distribution Agreement, and is not allowed on Google Play.

> Blockquote

After a regular review, we have determined that your app downloads, monetizes, or otherwise accesses YouTube videos in violation of the YouTube Terms of Service or YouTube API Terms of Service. Accessing content, a product, or service in an unauthorized manner is a violation of the Developer Distribution Agreement, and is not allowed on Google Play.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is not about programming ... Ask your lawyer.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/creating_monetizable_applications  From your description, I'm going to assume that since your app only displays a video (and no other content), that's not considered monetizable under the terms of service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems pretty self explanatory.

You're monetizing your YouTube channel outside of YouTube terms of service. It seems that that is your entire app.

Get around it by hosting your videos within the app or stream them from your own host somewhere else.

Doesn't matter where the ads are in your app.